# Tide without server frameworks

Tags: frameworks, graniteds

I am using GraniteDS and want to use Tide Framework, especially the data management feautures.

Do I need to use one of the server frameworks (EJB, Spring, Seam or CDI) to be able to use Tide framework ? All stacks suggested in documentation for server side, contains one of these server frameworks with additonal optional Tide framework. Also all tide configurations are given according to server framework and there is not any configuration for POJO services.

I have tried myself but I'm having a problem related with ServiceInvoker. My app uses SimpleServiceInvoker instead of TideServiceInvoker. I could not change the used implementation of ServiceInvoker without using configuration of one of the server side frameworks, and using frameworks configuration without using the framework itself caused other problems. Is there somebody using Tide without using these server frameworks, who can explain me the configuration for using TideServiceInvoker?

Thanks..